# ActiveMQ throws NullPointerException

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am using ActiveMQ in my application. Its behaving strangely at some time, when I start the Tomcat server and left it idle for few minutes, I am getting the below exception:

**Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:209)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.checkpointUpdate(MessageDatabase.java:1349)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$10.execute(MessageDatabase.java:814)
    at org.apache.kahadb.page.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:769)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase.checkpointCleanup(MessageDatabase.java:812)
    at org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase$3.run(MessageDatabase.java:324)**

**Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.isDebugEnabled(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:199)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.expireMessages(Queue.java:816)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue.access$100(Queue.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue$2.run(Queue.java:136)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)**

After this when the queue is called again, it throws the exception:

**Caught: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker**

I have used queue producer and consumer as shown below:

Producer:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "vm://localhost");

        // Create a Connection
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queuename);

        // Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        // Create a messages
        Iterator it = mapMessage.entrySet().iterator();
        MapMessage message = session.createMapMessage();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            message.setString(""+pairs.getKey(), ""+pairs.getValue());
            System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

        // Tell the producer to send the message
        System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message);
        producer.send(message);

        // Clean up
        session.close();
        connection.close();
```

Consumer:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "vm://localhost");

        // Create a Connection
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        // Create a Session
        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("register");

        // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(this);
```

ActiveMQ Integration:

```
PushRegisterConsumer prc = new PushRegisterConsumer();
    prc.start();

PushQueueProducer pmp = new PushQueueProducer();
pmp.queueProducer(AppConstants.QUEUE_NAME,registerDetails);
```

The producer and consumer has been integrated as shown above

Please help me resolving this issue.

Thanks,

Karthikeyan

Comment: Can you give some info around how ActiveMQ is wired in to your app? From the sounds of it, you have an embedded broker - is that right? Can you please also post up your ActiveMQ config.

Comment: Hi Jake. Thanks for your reply. Have modified my question with necessary information. Please provide your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` once, and pass it into the constructors of the `PushRegisterConsumer` and `PushRegisterProducer`. At the moment, it appears that 2 embedded brokers are being created with the name `localhost` - you want to ensure that this is only happening once only.